# scandir - how to get original folders - files order

Tags: php, scandir

items inside `fs` folder:

```
lorem  
ipsum  
sun  
moon.php  

function get_items($path){
    $arr = scandir($path);
    $arr = array_slice($arr, 2);
    foreach($arr as $el){
        if(is_dir($el)){
            echo "<div class='folder'>" . $el . "</div>\n";
        }
        else{
            echo "<div class='file'>" . $el . "</div>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Result - all items are echoed as class - `file` and in the following order:

```
ipsum  
lorem  
moon.php  
sun
```

How to get folders as `folder` and in original order - first folders and then files ?

lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

Comment: `lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum` is the correct order?

Comment: What *does* make you think `first folders and then files` is the `original order`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted may have issues because `scandir` return just the name of files and folders, not their absolute path.

When you later use `is_dir` you pass just the file/folder name (a relative path). When doing so, according to the [**documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php)

> If filename is a relative filename, it will be checked relative to the current working directory.

---

You can fix your code by passing a correct path to `is_dir`

`is_dir("$path/$el")`

In order for this solution to work `$path` must not have the trailing slash (because we **do** add it).

Furthermore `$path` must be either an absolute path to the target directory or a path to the target directory **relative** to the working directory the script is run.

---

Finally to list folders first then files you may sort the array or, more simply, make two `foreach` loops as follows:

```
function get_items($path){
    $arr = scandir($path);
    $arr = array_slice($arr, 2);

    sort($arr);

    // Folders first
    foreach($arr as $el){
        if(is_dir("$path/$el")){
            echo "<div class='folder'>" . $el . "</div>\n";
        }
    }

    // Then files
    foreach($arr as $el){
        if( ! is_dir("$path/$el")){
            echo "<div class='file'>" . $el . "</div>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You all ready have it.

```
 $path
```

So

```
$path.$el
```

Comment: do you mean - ` foreach($arr as $path.$el){` - this gives a syntax error

Comment: `echo "<div class='folder'>" . $path.$el . "</div>\n";`

Comment: I doubt that, did you remove the one you put in the loop?

Comment: did I remove - what? no, nothing is removed.

Comment: `do you mean -  foreach($arr as $path.$el){ - this gives a syntax error `

Comment: @puerto Your `foreach($arr as $el){` should remain as it was. Possibly the concatenation should be in the outputting (e.g. `echo "<div class='folder'>" . $path.$el . "</div>\n";`). Questions isn't clear to me